# Search Suggestions for django elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am using the [Django Elasticsearch DSL](https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl) library in order to integrate django with elasticsearch.

I have the search working properly and I am trying to also add the `suggestions` feature.

my `documents.py` is the following

```
# Name of the Elasticsearch index
INDEX = Index('search_movies')

# See Elasticsearch Indices API reference for available settings
INDEX.settings(
    number_of_shards=1,
    number_of_replicas=1
)


html_strip = analyzer(
    'html_strip',
    tokenizer="standard",
    filter=["standard", "lowercase", "stop", "snowball"],
    char_filter=["html_strip"]
)


@INDEX.doc_type
class MovieDocument(DocType):
    """Movie Elasticsearch document."""

    id = fields.IntegerField(attr='id')

    title = fields.StringField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.KeywordField(),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),

        }
    )

    summary = fields.StringField(
        analyzer=html_strip,
        fields={
            'raw': fields.KeywordField(),
        }
    )`
```

I have added the `'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),` as I saw it is required in order to get suggestions for that field.

I am trying then to use something similar as to what is shown [here](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#suggestions). So in my `views.py` i have the following

```
client = Elasticsearch()
search_in_title = 'search term goes here'

sreq = Search().using(client).query("multi_match", query=search_in_title, fields=['title', 'summary'])

ssug = sreq.suggest('title_suggestions', search_in_title, term={'field': 'title'})
```

but the `ssug` is always empty, so i am guessing i am using it the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the `title.suggest` sub-field instead:

```
ssug = s.suggest('title_suggestions', search_in_title, term={'field': 'title.suggest'})
                                                                         ^
                                                                         |
                                                                      add this
```

Comment: it still has the same behavior, when i am searching for a word like `example` both `sreq` and `ssug` find it. But when i search for `exmple` i get no result from both. My expectation was that the `ssug` would suggest the result shown previously when the word `example` was searched. Have I misunderstood the role of suggestions here?